# Adding Bootstrap class to button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem adding bootstrap class to button with a function. I want to add the disable class to #eng.

My code:

```
<li>
  <div class="btnLang">
      <form id="formLang1">
          <button id="slo" class="btn btn-mini disabled">slo</button>
      </form>

      <form id="formLang2" onsubmit='return eng_clicked()'>
          <button id="eng" class="btn btn-mini">eng</button>
       </form>
  </div>
</li>

<script type="text/javascript">
function eng_clicked(){
    $('#eng').addClass("disabled");
}
</script>
```

Comment: How do you send the form?, because with the button "eng" it doesnt, so the function eng_clicked is never fired and the class never added

Comment: I tried to fire the alert in my function and did worked but it doesn't when i am adding class.

Comment: Do you get any errors in Firebug/Web Inspector? I guess $ is not defined.

Comment: Are you sure it worked? the "eng_clicked" function it will be only fired if you have a submit input inside the form.

Comment: Nope. i don't get any.

Comment: sound's easy but yoy wrap your code with the tags of `script` http://jsfiddle.net/WVAgb/1/ because it should be working

Answer (score 2):

you forgot the script tag

```
<script type="Text/javascript">
//scripts
</script>
```

Anyway I have better solution for you using jQuery, just remove "onsubmit='return eng_clicked()'" and and replace the codes below instead of your codes:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#formLang2").click(function() {
  $('#eng').addClass("disabled");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

have you add the script tag?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function eng_clicked(){
    $('#eng').addClass("disabled");
}
</script>
```